# Application of MVT to find the limit

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

The question I'm trying to answer is as follows,

Evaluate the limit $\int_0^1 f_n$ where $f_n(x) = \frac{\sqrt{n}(e^{-x/n}-1)}{x}$

I know that I want to use a theorem stating that if $f_n \rightarrow f$ uniformly on [a,b] and $f_n \in R_a^b$ then $f \in R_a^b$ and $lim_n \int_a^b f_n(t)dt = \int_a^b f(t)dt$

If I can show that $lim_n =0$ then that proves that $\int_0^1 f_n = 0$

I was informed that I should focus on simplifying [$e^{\frac{-x}{n}}-1$] using the mean value theorem, but I'm confused on how exactly I would do that. Any help would be great!

note:  $R_a^b$ is the set of Riemann integrable functions on [a,b]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to show *uniform* convergence to zero, not just convergence to zero.

Applying MVT to the function $f(x) = e^{-x}$ tells us for a given $x\in[0,1],$ we have $$ \frac{|e^{-x/n}-1|}{x/n} = e^{-c/n}$$ for some $c\in[0,x].$ This means that $$\frac{|e^{-x/n}-1|}{x/n} \le 1 $$ and therefore we have $$ \left|\frac{\sqrt n (e^{-x/n}-1)}{x}\right| \le \frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}$$ for all $x\in [0,1].$ This shows that the sequence of functions converges uniformly to zero.